# Jump parameter in function

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, uri, parameter-passing

I have a controller in codeigniter called 'Main' with this function:

```
public function index ($id = false, $filter ='htmlentities') {
    ...
    ...

    }
```

I want to call it through the URI 'jumping' the first parameter so that it remains 'false':
I would like to be able through the URI using something like:

```
'main/index/false/myfilter'
```

However this doesn't work, does anyone know how can I 'jump' this first parameter so that its value remains being false but i am able to change the filter?

**(changing parameter order in function is NOT an option)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test for the string `'false'` at the top of the controller method:

```
public function index ($id = false, $filter ='htmlentities') {
  if ($id == 'false') {
    $id = false;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Another possibility might be to use a [custom route](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) and simply discard the first parameter. In your `app/config/routes.php` file, add the rule:

```
$route['main/index/:filter'] = 'main/index/false/$1';
```

Now, when you visit 'main/index/myfilter', the `$id` parameter will be set to `false` (a string, not a boolean!)

Comment: Ok. Could you clarify the question, then?

Comment: Well, just using the uri, can you do it?

Comment: Still not quite sure what you're asking, but check my addendum re: custom routing.

Comment: That should do it :) as long as I dont touch the function it is ok!